# HTTP Authorization Header is not being passed to handler in Google Cloud Functions (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, http, flask, authorization, google-cloud-functions

I'm handling http requests sent from mobile clients using Google Cloud Functions and it seems like some of the request headers are not being passed from the GCF flask wrapper to my handler function. The docs are not very clear on that, the only reference i found on Authorization is on how to setup CORS. 
Any idea how I can still get the Authorization barrier token? 
These the headers I do get:

> ```
> [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'), 
> ('Host', 'us-central1-XXXXXXXXX.cloudfunctions.net'), 
>  ('User-Agent', 'analytics-ios/3.7.0-beta.3'), 
>  ('Accept', '*/*'), 
>  ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip'), 
>  ('Accept-Language', 'en-us'), 
>  ('Content-Encoding', 'gzip'), 
>  ('Function-Execution-Id', 'XXXXXXXXX'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Api-Ticket', 'XXXXXXXXX'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-City', 'tel aviv-yafo'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Citylatlong', '32.085300,34.781768'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Country', 'IL'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Default-Version-Hostname', 'XXXXXXXXX-tp.appspot.com'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Https', 'on'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Region', 'ta'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-Request-Log-Id', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX......XXXXXXXXX'), 
>  ('X-Appengine-User-Ip', 'XXXXXXXXX'), 
>  ('X-Cloud-Trace-Context', XXXXXXXXX....XXXXXXXXX'), 
>  ('X-Forwarded-For', 'XXXXXXXXX'), 
>  ('X-Forwarded-Proto', 'https')]
> ```

Comment: The header name is `Authorization`. I have no problems passing that header in HTTP requests to Cloud Functions. Double check that the client is actually sending this header and correctly. The value is `Bearer xxxxx`.

Comment: thanks. when I'm running a local Flask server and directing my mobile clients request traffic there, I am getting the header. btw, the sdk i'm using does HTTP Basic auth so the header is Basic XXXXX